# Why can't I open the Creative Cloud folder in terminal

Tags: terminal, folders

I am new to the terminal but find the ability to navigate folders quite handy, so I wanted to cd into the Creative Cloud Files folder but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working do you know what may be the cause here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the folder *Creative Cloud Files* you have to escape spaces in the folder name:

```
cd Creative\ Cloud\ Files
```

or use quotation marks:

```
cd "Creative Cloud Files"
```

You can also use the tab key after entering the first letters which will then auto-expand the folder name if the entered string is unique in the directory:

`cd Cre` <kbd>tab</kbd> which will expand to `cd Creative\ Cloud\ Files/`then.

If the same directory also contains a folder e.g. *Credentials* you have to enter an additional character (which makes the string unique) to get an auto-completed folder name.